# Is a reciprocal number written with omitted “1” easily recognisable as a reciprocal number?

Tags: notation

Reciprocal of a number $x$ equals $1 / x$. Negative of a number $x$ equals $0 − x$, but, usually, the $-$ is treated as a unary operator, so the $0$ is omitted ($-x$). If I write reciprocation as unary division ($/x$), would it be widely recognised as a reciprocal? I think that I use reciprocals often enough that such notation would make the text noticeably less cluttered in some places, and I'd rather not explain it every time I would use it.

I have two situations for this:

1. In a thesis. Reciprocation isn't much related to the topic of the thesis, so maybe an introduction of such notation would seem out of place.
2. In everyday communication. Often, there is not enough space or time to explain it, like when I leave a note or send a quick e-mail. And, even if I explained it, it would probably make the whole message longer.

Edit: I think that reciprocation is an elementary operation; that's why I think that it should have its own unary operation. I didn't realise it when I was writing this question, but Angel reminded me of it in the answer. I wrote that negation is subtraction from $0$ because subtraction has been used longer in history than negation as far as I know, but I didn't express it well; I too think that negation is more elementary than subtraction.

Edit: I replaced all instances of “÷” with “/” so people can't complain about using “÷”.

Comment: Maybe you can write $x^{-1}$? If I understand correctly...

Comment: I would stick to $1/x$. It's only one character more than any unary operator you could invent. Any such invention will derail your readers.

Comment: You're asking about the ability of your readers to understand your choice of notation, which is difficult for anyone to speculate on unless they know something about your audience.  I can tell you that the notation $/x$ is uncommon in mathematical papers, and either $1/x$ or $x^{-1}$ is preferred.  (Note by the way that it's not quite accurate to say that $-x$ is shorthand for $0-x$.  Rather, $0-x$ is shorthand for $0+(-x)$.)

Comment: You may be interested in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory), but in answer to your question, write $1/x$ or $x^{-1}$, not $/x$.

Answer (score 2):

To turn two comments into an answer:
No, there is no such notation but you can write $x^{-1}$, $1/x$ or $\frac1x$.

In a thesis you should definitely use one of them to be consistent with existing mathematics. In particular the symbol $÷$ is anywhere in mathematics after primary school used (correct me if I am ignorant).

For everyday communication $1/x$ is probably easiest as you wrote yourself and you usually don't have LaTeX available.

Note that x⁻¹ is also possible without LaTeX if you can type the unicode letters [Superscript minus](https://unicode-table.com/en/207B/) and [superscript 1](https://unicode-table.com/en/00B9/) at your keyboard.

Comment: I used “÷” because it's the basic division symbol, even in LATEX (its macro is “\div” for “division”), but I use “/” (maybe “:”) if I write division by hand or in plain text (and even in LATEX). I think that “÷” is the most recognisable division symbol; “/” and “:” could have other functions.

LATEX isn't needed for any conventional notation of division except $\frac{a}{b}$.

Comment: Oddly enough, your superscript minus here doesn't display on my phone even though I can see the character on other sites. I think it must be a font issue on StackExchange.

Comment: @matj1 Probably the difference in our perception is that I am a math student and only see the notation there and in other disciplines ÷ is used. Or it's (also) regional thing: I am from Germany.
`\div` being ÷ always surprised me when I noticed it and wanted to get $\operatorname{div}$ (Divergence).

Answer (score 2):

The notation $\div$ for division is not used anywhere at all, except outside the context of the very first years of primary education in mathematics. Anyone who is older than $12$-years old is more likely to use the notation $a/b$ or $\frac{a}{b}$ to denote division. So if you are frequently communicating division to other people at work, then you should be using the notation $a/b,$ not $a\div{b}.$ With that being said, the notation $\div{x}$ to denote the reciprocal of $x$ would come off as extremely awkward. Instead, you would do better using the notation $/x,$ which is completely analogous to what you are suggesting, but better... but even then, this would be confusing.

So, in actuality, it is just as flukx said. If you want to denote the reciprocal of $x$ using symbolic notation, then you really should stick to using standard mathematical notation that everyone is familiar with for denoting the reciprocal, notation such as $x^{-1}$ or $1/x.$ I recommend the notation $x^{-1},$ simply because this renders the notion of reciprocal as a unary operator more naturally. The symbol $1/x$ is already unfortunately associated with division, so this may not convey the notion of a unary operator properly.

Also, your explanation of $-x$ and $0-x$ is incorrect. It is not the case that $-x$ is a shorthand for $0-x.$ Rather, $0-x$ is a shorthand for $0+(-x).$ This may come as a shock, but it really is not the case that subtraction is an elementary operation in algebraic structures. Additive inversion is the elementary operation, and subtraction is derived from combining addition with additive inversion. Similarly, division is not an elementary arithmetic operation. Reciprocation is the elementary operation, and division is the result of combining it with multiplication. This is why you cannot divide by $0$: it stems from the fact that the multiplicative inverse of $0$ in an arbitrary ring (and even in some weaker structures) does/cannot exist. The reason it makes no sense to divide in many structures where multiplication makes sense is because there is no appropriate notion of a multiplicative inverse. $a/b$ is a shorthand for $a\cdot{b^{-1}},$ and $1/x$ is a shorthand for $1\cdot{x^{-1}},$ not the other way around. This is yet another reason why you should really use the notation $x^{-1},$ instead of what you are proposing.

Comment: “Reciprocation is the elementary operation, and division is the result of combining it with multiplication.” – I thought about that when I came up with using unary division as reciprocation. I think that reciprocation should have its own operator if it's an elementary operation. I wrote that negation is subtraction from 0 because our civilisation knew subtraction first and negative numbers later AFAIK, but I didn't express it well. — As I wrote elsewhere, I used “÷” here because it's the most recognisable symbol for division, but I use usually “/” or “:”.

Comment: "I think that reciprocation should have its own operator if it's an elementary operation." I am not sure what you mean here. $x^{-1}$ unambiguously denotes the reciprocal of $x.$ So this *is* the symbol for reciprocation. Are you inquiring about a symbol that denotes reciprocation *without* the input? In the same fashion that we talk about the operations $+$ and $\cdot$ without having any objects attached to them symbolically?

Comment: $a^b$ is a binary operator of powering. That $a^{-1} = /a$ is only a special case of powering if $b$ is fixed to $-1$. That's why I don't consider it reciprocation's own operator. Reciprocation relates to only one number, so its own operator should be unary.

Comment: "$a^b$ is a binary operator of powering." It really is not, though. $a^b$ is not well-defined unless $b$ is a natural number, and this also assumes that $a$ is an element of a monoid on $\cdot.$ This is not a particularly strong assumption, and if the monoid is  a group, then $a^{-1}$ is well-defined, and so we define $a^{-n}:=\left(a^{-1}\right)^n,$ but this really is just notation, it does not formally represent an operation on an algebraic structure. Beyond that, $a^b$ is not well-defined for other values of $b,$ except within very specific and rare algebraic structures.

Comment: Unlike $a+b$ or $a\cdot{b},$ $a^n$ is merely a matter of notation, not algebra. The only real reason this notation $a^n$ even exists to start with is due to the importance of polynomial rings and series rings. It serves as a nice way of labeling the basis for polynomials and a certain type of function sequence, while also incorporating a Cauchy product that is nicely notated. But it does not actually represent an operation in itself.

Comment: What is operation? My idea is that each operation is a function written with an operator, which is a form taking values and representing a single value being the result of the function on the given values. It's like [operators in Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Infix_operator), which are just a different way to write function application. According to that, powering is an operation because it has its function and its form. [The article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_(mathematics)) agrees with that idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134883/discussion-between-angel-and-matj1).